# JavaScript GitHub Action running on windows-latest to upload directory or file into S3

Tags: amazon-s3, github-actions

With `runs-on: ubuntu-latest`, I quickly found a marketplace Docker action to upload a generated directory into S3 and setup a perfectly working pipeline.

But I need to do the same with `runs-on: windows-latest`, where Docker actions no longer work.

Tried the other available alternative, to build aJavaScript action. But after testing several different `npm` packages I did not succeed.

I would like also the action to be as much as possible self contained in the `.yml` file (of course accessing the needed GitHub Secrets for AWS key, id, bucket..).

Anybody has already encountered the same problem and can point me to a possible solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [stcalica/s3-upload](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/aws-update-s3-action) action. It is written in JavaScript and it seems it does the work that you need.

Comment: Thank you @fabasoad it works well. Not sure if it can upload a directory, it seems to me that `package` accepts only single files.